# How to prove $\sum_{n\geq 0}{\frac{\Gamma(n+2+\alpha)}{n!\Gamma(2+\alpha)}z^n}=\frac{1}{(1-z)^{2+\alpha}}$

Tags: power-series, gamma-function, bergman-spaces

Let $z\in \{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}, \alpha>-1,\Gamma(s)$ is the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

How to prove $\sum_{n\geq 0}{\frac{\Gamma(n+2+\alpha)}{n!\Gamma(2+\alpha)}z^n}=\frac{1}{(1-z)^{2+\alpha}}$ ?

If $\alpha=0,$ then [it is easy to get the above result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn).
How can i prove the above general result?

Comment: it is not true. do you know the Taylor expansion of $(1-z)^{\beta}$ around $z=0$ ? (when $\beta \not \in \mathbb{Z}$)

Comment: take a look at [the binomial_series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_and_connection_to_the_binomial_series)

Comment: $$\Gamma(n+2+\alpha) = \Gamma( n-1 + 2 + \alpha)*(n+1+\alpha)=\cdots = \Gamma(n-n+2+\alpha)*(2+\alpha)\cdots (n+1+\alpha)$$

So now we have

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(n+1+\alpha)^{(n)}}{n!} z^n$$ (underline in the notation of wikipedia) What you want for the pruported RHS would be $\binom{-2}{n}$ instead.

Comment: @AHusain@user1952009.Thank you. There is a type-error of problem. I re-edited my problem and I think I can fix it by your methods.